# EC2 Autoscaling issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat6, autoscaling, lampp

I am stuck with one issue while auto scaling. My EC2 Instance has XAMPP and tomcat, on scaling up the newly created instance does not automatically start tomcat and I even have to manually do port mapping under lampp folder using

root@domu-xx-xx-xx lampp]# /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

root@domu-xx-xx-xx lampp]# /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8085 -j REDIRECT --to-port 91

root@domu-xx-xx-xx lampp]#/sbin/iptables-save

How can I a) Automate tomcat start up on instance creation and b) Automate above port mapping so that auto scaled instance is up & running without any manual intervention.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all this to `/etc/rc.local` file to get it executed on server start-up. Create your own AMI and start your auto-scaled instanced with this AMI.

e.g.

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8085 -j REDIRECT --to-port 91
/sbin/iptables-save
/path/to/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
/any/others/script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, can you please elaborate and point me to what exactly do I put in rc.local for port mapping & tomcat startup. It would be really helpful

Comment: rc.local is a shell executable script that would get executed on system boot. You can add all your commands there.

Comment: OK...let me check this out ! Have you tried this with EC2 instance

Comment: Not exactly but similar things. EC2 is same as any other PC. You just boot with your custom OS/AMI that has the script and it should work.

Comment: Ashish, I need to run those port mapping commands under lampp folder - otherwise it won't be able to find those commands

Comment: You can do `cd` on 1st line.

Comment: Since you are setting iptables with full path, why would you need it to be in executed in specific directory?

Comment: I gave it a try but the port mappings didn't work. I had to do them manually on the new instance. Below is the copy of my /etc/rc.local

Comment: I have posted copy of my code in your answer. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a ton. +1. It seems last time multiple commands for mapping were copied as a single line (so it gave error).